# UIUserNotificationSettings refusing to accept multiple notification types in swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, xcode7

I am trying to get swift to send a notification.  This is the code I have in the appdelegate.swift file that is registering the notification

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(
    UIUserNotificationSettings(
        forTypes:UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, categories: nil))
```

I get this error:

> Binary operator '|' to two 'UIUserNotificationType' operands.

If you could help me get a solution for this problem that would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 19):

Try this

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge , .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

**First:** import UserNotification

```
import UserNotifications
```

**Second:** Then add delegate to appDelegate :

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, **UIApplicationDelegate**
```

**Third:** Then Register notifications :

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
        {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
            center.delegate = self
            //center.setNotificationCategories(nil)
            center.requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Alert,.Badge,.Sound]) {
                granted,error in
                if (error == nil) {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization. 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUser‌NotificationSettings‌(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
    }
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

**Swift 4.0**

Do above steps then register notification on the main thread like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
              UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
})
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer does resolve the error. However, your settings declaration includes alert and badge, but not sound. That's not going to be a problem?

Comment: @DaveG sound added. Thank you.

Comment: ```if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
            }
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
        }
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()    ```

swift 3, with fallback for earlier versions of iOS

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside AppDelegate try this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil))
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

    return true
}
```